# OpenCL convert float16 to float*

Tags: c++, opencl

Currently I am working on a kernel, that can be optimized using float16 types. However, I did not find any documentation about converting float16 into float*, because my output variable is a float*. Here is the sample code

```
_kernel void IncrementMatrix( __global float* Source, __global float* Target, __global float* out )
{
   const int globalID = get_global_id(0);
   float16 S = vload16( globalID , Source );
   float16 T = vload16( globalID , Target );
   S = S + T;
   out[globalID*16] = (float*)S; // this is not working    
}
```

I already tried this **out = (float*)S;**, but it is giving invalid type conversion error.

Comment: You don&#39;t need to convert it to a pointer, you need to convert it to a `float` (because `out[globalID * 16]` is a `float`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like you use `vload16()` to load the data use [vstore16](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/vstoren.html) to store it

like this:

```
vstore16(S, globalID, out)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and its worked perfectly :)